# How to write a function that checks if an item is in a tree?

Tags: list, lisp

I have to write a function that checks if an item is in a tree.

For example:

```
(defun find-in-tree (item tree)
  ...)

(find-in-tree 2 '(1 (3 4 (2))) 2) ;; should give T
(find-in-tree 2 '(1 (3 4))) ;; should give NIL
```

Comment: This seems like homework. If so, it should be labeled as such.

Comment: We can't help unless we know what you have tried already, and what _specific_ issues you don't understand.

Comment: This question is vague. The examples suggest that a tree search (not a list search) is going on.  The standard `member` function will not find `(2)` at a deeper level of nesting. The syntax `myMember(list, item)` isn't Lisp; is it part of the homework to parse that syntax? Also `(2)` is an invalid expression, trying to call `2` as a function.

Comment: Just for the record, this isn't "off topic", it's "not a real question".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [On Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html):

> Finally, consider `rfind-if`, a recursive version of `find-if` which works on trees as well as flat lists:
>
> ```
> (defun rfind-if (fn tree)
>   (if (atom tree)
>       (and (funcall fn tree) tree)
>       (or (rfind-if fn (car tree))
>           (if (cdr tree) (rfind-if fn (cdr tree))))))
> ```

Few examples:

```
CL-USER> (find-if #'(lambda (x) (eq x 2)) '(1 (3 4 (2)))) ;; FIND-IF is the standard function
NIL
CL-USER> (rfind-if #'(lambda (x) (eq x 2)) '(1 (3 4 (2))))
2
CL-USER> (rfind-if #'(lambda (x) (eq x 2)) '((1 (2) 3) (3 4)))
2
CL-USER> (rfind-if #'(lambda (x) (eq x 2)) '((1 3) (3 4)))
NIL
CL-USER> (rfind-if (fint #'numberp #'oddp) '(2 (3 4) 5))
3
```

Now, a recursive version of `find`:

```
(defun find/tree (item tree &optional (test #'eq))
  (rfind-if #'(lambda (el) (funcall test el item)) tree))
```

Usage:

```
CL-USER> (find 2 '((1 (2) 3) (3 4))) ;; FIND is the standard function, again
NIL
CL-USER> (find/tree 2 '((1 (2) 3) (3 4)))
2
CL-USER> (find/tree "2" '((1 ("2") 3) (3 4)))
NIL
CL-USER> (find/tree "2" '((1 ("2") 3) (3 4)) #'equal)
"2"
```

You can find out more about lists, trees, recursive functions and recursive search in [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), [On Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html) and [PAIP](http://norvig.com/paip.html).

---

There is also a question of whether these functions are tail-recursive or not. Such issues are also discussed in listed books.